# LDAP JAVA and userPassword

Tags: java, spring, ldap, openldap

i have a JAVA application built with spring-ldap that can modify user's userPassword in an openldap server. I want to use md5 storage or any encryption technique but when my application modify the userPassword attribute it seems that the base64 hash is escaped. It results in "invalid credentials" when i try to authenticate the user with the new password...

For example when i use this code :

```
context.setAttribute(new BasicAttribute("userPassword", "{md5}DMF1ucDxtqgxw5niaXcmYQ=="));
template.modifyAttributes(dn, context.getModificationItems());
```

and look at the userPassword attribute with Apache Directory Studio i get

```
{md5}DMF1ucDxtqgxw5niaXcmYQ\=\=
```

The "verify" password function success but not the authentication. When i use Apache Directory Studio to modify the hash and remove unnecessary '\' characters, authentication success.

Is it possible to prevent spring-ldap from escaping the hashed password ? Is there any known solution to this problem ?

Thanks.

Comment: Feels more like a problem of JNDI than a thin Spring LDAP layer above it.

Comment: I feel some inconsistency in your question... this should really not happen. Can you try to check what is being sent over the wire (e.g. via tcpdump or wireshark)?

Answer (score 0):

If the LDAP server is correctly configured it should do the hashing for you. You should just send the plaintext password, over SSL of course.